# How to get Internet Address from Lotus Notes

Tags: c#, ldap, lotus-notes

A Notes calendar entry has an Item called "Chair", which is a distinguished name along the lines of "CN=My Name/OU=Something/O=SomethingElse". How do I convert this to an SMTP address such as "my.name@company.com"? I tried looking at NotesName which has an Addr821 property, but  this only seems to work if you give it an SMTP address - when given a distinguished name, Addr821 gives you back the same thing.

One option I see is to use the address book, but how do I look it up using a distinguished name?

I assume I could look it up using LDAP, but how does my code find out the LDAP server (which in this case is Novell)?

Any help would be appreciated.

I am using c# with Interop.Domino.dll.

Answer (score 7):

I've never used interop.domino.dll, but I think these approaches might help you:

If you can use the `evaluate` function, you could use the `@NameLookup` formula:

```
evaluate("@NameLookup([Exhaustive];Chair;'InternetAddress')",CalendarDocument)
```

Another approach is to "manually" look the name up in the Domino Directory:

- Go through `session.addressbooks`, find one that's public and on a server.
- Get the view `$VIMPeople`.
- `getDocumentByKey` using the abbreviated name format.

*Edit*

Here is (untested) LotusScript code to get the InternetAddress for a given user, it should be relatively easy to translate into c#:

```
Function GetInternetAddress(username as string) as string
    On Error Goto errorthrower
    dim session as new NotesSession
    dim dominodirectory as NotesDatabase
    dim notesusername as new NotesName(username)


    forall candidate in session.AddressBooks
        if candidate.isPublicAddressBook and candidate.Server <> "" then
            set dominodirectory = candidate
            exit forall
        end if
    end forall

    if dominodirectory is nothing then error 1900,"Failed to find Domino Directory."
    if not dominodirectory.isOpen then call dominodirectory.open("","")

    dim view as NotesView
    set view = dominodirectory.getView("$VIMPeople")

    dim document as notesdocument
    set document = view.getDocumentByKey(notesusername.Abbreviated, true)
    if document is nothing then error 1900,"Failed to find document matching '" & username & "'"

    GetInternetAddress = document.InternetAddress(0)

    Exit Function
ErrorThrower:
    Error Err, Error & Chr(13) + "Module: " & Cstr( Getthreadinfo(1) ) & ", Line: " & Cstr( Erl )
End Function
```

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate on the "getDocumentByKey using the abbreviated name format" please?

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim session As NotesSession
    Dim directory As NotesDirectory

    Set session = New NotesSession
    Set directory = session.GetDirectory("")

    Dim mailinfo As Variant
    Dim ooo As String   
    Dim mailmsg As String   
    Dim mailname As String  
    'mailname = Inputbox$("Name of user")
    On Error Goto mailerror 
    ''''''''The Paremeters mean, GetMailInfo(The userName,GetServerInfo?,Flasg Error incase of Multiple Names Found?)
    'mailinfo = directory.GetMailInfo(mailname, False, True)
    mailinfo = directory.GetMailInfo("Eliud Ngugi", False, True)
    On Error Goto 0 

    Messagebox  "Internet Address "  & mailinfo(7) ,64
    Exit Sub
    mailerror:  
        Messagebox  Error(),, "Error number " & Err()
        Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go manually: open up the Names.nsf or use 'Directory Assistance' (details escape me), open up the $Users view and locate the users 'person' document using Abbreviated UserName (derived from the 'chair' name), locate and use the 'InternetAddress' field value. This presumes that this field has been populated with the 'current/real' email address.

While $Vim views (and others) can be useful, you might have more work to do to disambiguate user names in large orgainsations to derive the correct form of the name matching required.

$Users view can match on Abbreviated, Common User name, first, last, shortname and soundex and is generally the most useful 'lookup' view. It is most likely to be 'fully built' as the main notes mail router uses this view to route emails.

To convert the name to the 'distinguished format' use either **@name([Abbreviate]; name)** or the LotusScript equivalent: Something like:

```
dim n as new notesName
Set n = session.CreateName(canonical/distinguished/name)
distname = n.abbreviated
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)

    Dim session As NotesSession
    Dim directory As NotesDirectory

    Set session = New NotesSession
    Set directory = session.GetDirectory("")

    Dim mailinfo As Variant
    Dim ooo As String   
    Dim mailmsg As String   
    Dim mailname As String  
    'mailname = Inputbox$("Name of user")
    On Error Goto mailerror 
    ''''''''The Paremeters mean, GetMailInfo(The userName,GetServerInfo?,Flasg Error incase of Multiple Names Found?)
    mailinfo = directory.GetMailInfo(mailname, False, True)
    mailinfo = directory.GetMailInfo("Eliud Ngugi", False, True)
    On Error Goto 0 

    Messagebox  "Internet Address "  & mailinfo(7) ,64
    Exit Sub
mailerror:  
    Messagebox  Error(),, "Error number " & Err()
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If they have Novell Identity Manager, which would be synchronizing data from multiple sources to other multiple destinations, and you have an eDirectory instance to use for LDAP connectivity, just read back the Mail attribute.

Now it depends on how the sync to Notes is handled.  I usually would store the Notes fully distinguished name in an attribute in eDirectory, since as you have noted, it is useful to have.

However, if the class of this "Chair" object is not a User nor a group, it is likely they are not synchronizing it.  (Mail in DB's are a common third class that might be possible).